# Appending options to select in modal

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I am trying to append a list of options to a select in a modal but they don't appear, looking for ideas!

After the main page loads, I trigger the modal by clicking a link that runs:

```
$("#tankTransfer").click(function (e) {
   $('#modalBox').load('modalTest.html', function () {
               // init select ----------
               document.getElementById("textId").innerHTML = "Testing Modal Select Append";
               $('#selectId').append($("<option></option>").attr("optionName", 
                                     "optionValue").text("optionText"));
               document.getElementById("textId").innerHTML = "Select should have optionText in the list";
           });
        });
```

Rather than using jQuery I have also tried inserting options via:

```
       var spinner = document.getElementById("selectId");
       spinner.add(option, option.text);
       spinner.refresh();
```

None of the above works. I have also tried calling the append/add via a button click within the modal. But it still doesn't append/add... I tried switching the *selectId* to a select that is in the body of the main page to append/add to that one and it shows just fine. It just won't show on the modal. The *textId* updates just fine and shows the code doesn't crap out and no errors are thrown.

Also, I've tried adding the code after the jQuery append:

```
    $('#selectId').change();
```

With this in the modal:

```
 $('#selectId').change(function (e) {
        var oValue = getSpinnerNameAttributeValue('selectId', "optionName");
        alert(oValue);
    });
```

And I get the appended *optionValue*.

Here's an example of the #modalBox: t the appended optionValue.

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" id="textId">From Tank</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectId">
                        <option optionName="-1">None</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any and all insights, solutions, and understanding!

Comment: Please show us an example of the `#modalBox` after the html has been loaded

Comment: That's a strange way to add a option. Have you tried just doing:
`$('#selectId').append('<option value="OptionValue">OptionText</option>')`

Comment: I edited my question to include the modalBox html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the lack of creative answers from the community here, I guessed that there's no issue with appending to a select in a modal.

I finally found the bug in my code: I had a select in the main body with the same element `id` as the one in the modal. So, when appending to the select only the select in the main body was appended and the modal's select remained unchanged.